# Android: set wallpaper to fit the screen

Tags: java, android

I have the code to setting a wallpaper (android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER is needed)

```
// this is inside activity
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

My question is, how can I adjust this code in order to set the wallpaper to fit the screen both options:

1. If image resolution is lower than the screen resolution - stretch
   it.
2. If image resolution is higher than the screen resolution - scale it down.

Note: I have already tried to scale the bitmap to the screen's resolution before setting it as wallpaper, but it actually looked even worth than without scaling.

Comment: maybe resize the bitmap to fit the screen? Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

Comment: Tamir, I have already tried that, to scale the bitmap to the screen's resolution, but it looked even worth... It is really strange.

Comment: Do you want the image to fill the screen or fit the image completely within the screen boundary?

Comment: I want it to fit the screen. Enlarge or reduce according to the image and screen resolution ratios

Answer (score -1):

I made an app to set wallpapers and I tryed alot of things... the one that really worked for me its this method :

```
// Crop or inflate bitmap to desired device height and/or width
public Bitmap prepareBitmap(final Bitmap sampleBitmap,
                            final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager) {
    Bitmap changedBitmap = null;
    final int heightBm = sampleBitmap.getHeight();
    final int widthBm = sampleBitmap.getWidth();
    final int heightDh = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
    final int widthDh = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
    if (widthDh > widthBm || heightDh > heightBm) {
        final int xPadding = Math.max(0, widthDh - widthBm) / 2;
        final int yPadding = Math.max(0, heightDh - heightBm) / 2;
        changedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthDh, heightDh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final int[] pixels = new int[widthBm * heightBm];
        sampleBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, widthBm, 0, 0, widthBm, heightBm);
        changedBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, widthBm, xPadding, yPadding,
                widthBm, heightBm);
    } else if (widthBm > widthDh || heightBm > heightDh) {
        changedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthDh, heightDh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int cutLeft = 0;
        int cutTop = 0;
        int cutRight = 0;
        int cutBottom = 0;
        final Rect desRect = new Rect(0, 0, widthDh, heightDh);
        Rect srcRect = new Rect();
        if (widthBm > widthDh) { // crop width (left and right)
            cutLeft = (widthBm - widthDh) / 2;
            cutRight = (widthBm - widthDh) / 2;
            srcRect = new Rect(cutLeft, 0, widthBm - cutRight, heightBm);
        } else if (heightBm > heightDh) { // crop height (top and bottom)
            cutTop = (heightBm - heightDh) / 2;
            cutBottom = (heightBm - heightDh) / 2;
            srcRect = new Rect(0, cutTop, widthBm, heightBm - cutBottom);
        }
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(changedBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sampleBitmap, srcRect, desRect, null);

    } else {
        changedBitmap = sampleBitmap;
    }
    return changedBitmap;
}
```

The code it's from [this manual](https://www.teusink.eu/2014/11/load-bitmap-efficiently-and-set-it-as.html) where you will find more methods to properly resize an image.